# Simple C# CPU stress test. Having issue terminating the test

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace StressTest
{
    class CPU_Stress_Test
    {
        public static void waste_time()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if ( 1 == 1 )
                {
                    int temp = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userInput;
            int numThreads;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Number of threads to run:");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            numThreads = Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
            //Console.WriteLine("You Entered {0}", numThreads);

            Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreads];

            for ( int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++ )
            {
                threads[i] =  new Thread(waste_time);
                threads[i].Start();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Stress Test Started using {0}",numThreads);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Stop Stress Test");
            Console.ReadKey();
            
            for ( int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i )
            {
                threads[i].Join();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Stress Test Ended Press Any Key to Exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
    }

  

}
```

Hello everyone. I am attempting to get back into programming and I'm having a bit of trouble with a simple multithreaded CPU stress test that I am trying to code in C#.net.

My code is above.

It Prompts to user to enter the number of threads for the stress test.
I then allocate an array of threads based on the users input.
I use a for loop to iterate through the thread array to initialize each thread in the array and then call .Start() on each thread.
The code then outputs a message telling the user to press any key to stop the stress test.

once the user presses a key I use another for loop to .Join() all the threads and ending the stress test.

Using the the debugger in VS2022 I was able to ascertain that the program seems to fail when attempting to .Join() the threads in the final for loop.

I feel like I am missing something obvious here. But it has been a long time since I was in school for CS and I had stopped coding for a while. So please forgive me if the solution is something obvious.

Thanks for your help. It is very much appreciated

Comment: I assume by "seems to fail" you mean that `Console.WriteLine("Stress Test Ended Press Any Key to Exit");` is never executed.  `Join()` will never return because you never signal for the threads/`waste_time()` to exit and `waste_time()` never checks for such a signal/condition.  Also, `1 == 1` can be evaluated at compile-time and, since it's always `true`, I would expect to be optimized away.

Comment: You might need to call `.Abort()` on the threads to stop them.  Or set some sort of variable in your loop, such as `while(shouldIStillRun)` instead of `while(true)`

Comment: So .Abort() throws an exception when I try execute the program however it does achieve the desired behavior. However I'm much more interested in your other suggestions concerning my wast_time() function. Is there any way to pass or update  an argument to a function currently being run by a thread? That way I could set up the while loop to check if the thread should still run.

Comment: Yea, you'd have to use a static variable in the `CPU_Stress_Test` class, and set it to false when you want to stop running..  You could also try/catch the ThreadAbort exception and exit gracefully.

Comment: That did the trick. thank you very much.

Comment: Don't call `Thread.Abort()`. It's a bad idea. The latest versions of the framework have deprecated it.

Answer (score 3):

Threads have to end naturally for a `Join` to work. You have to signal the loop to end.

Here's a version that uses a `CancellationToken`  to do that.

```
public static void waste_time(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (1 == 1)
        {
            int temp = 0;
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Number of threads to run:");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    int numThreads = int.TryParse(userInput, out int x) ? x : -1;

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

    var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, numThreads).Select(_ => new Thread(() => waste_time(cts.Token))).ToList();
    
    threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());
    
    Console.WriteLine("Stress Test Started using {0}", numThreads);
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Stop Stress Test");
    Console.ReadLine();

    cts.Cancel();

    threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());

    Console.WriteLine("Stress Test Ended Press Enter to Exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```